# Can you use 1 ssrs report server(and report) for multiple SQL Server instances

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a bunch of reports that are using the same shared data source, however we are not wanting to run the same reports off of data on another server. I would like to avoid having to copy all the reports to another instance of SSRS and have the data source be dynamically driven by a parameter.

Is this possible with a shared data source?

Also we are using SQL Server 2012.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions to build datasource connections but ONLY if the connection is embedded in the report, shared datasources can NOT be dynamic in the same way.

One way around this, but it's messy and not very safe, is to use linked servers and then include the server name in the table references. To do this you would have to use dynamic sql - not pretty if you have large dataset queries.